# Creating asset filter throws 400 Bad Request

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm trying to create a filter for a stream, basically just to clip it.The asset corresponds to a live stream that's still ongoing.

This is my call through the .net sdk (Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media, Version=2.0.1.0), which fails with a 400 and no additional information:

```
                await _client.AssetFilters.CreateOrUpdateAsync(_config.ResourceGroup, _config.AccountName,
                    _assetName, filterName, new AssetFilter()
                    {
                        PresentationTimeRange = new PresentationTimeRange()
                        {
                            StartTimestamp = 100000000,
                            EndTimestamp = 150000000,
                            LiveBackoffDuration = 0,
                            Timescale = 10000000,
                            ForceEndTimestamp = false
                        },
                        Tracks = new List<FilterTrackSelection>()
                    });
```

Trying to do the same via an http request succeeds, the filter is created and can be used:

```
                    var uri =
                        $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{_config.SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{_config.ResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/streaming/assets/{_assetName}/assetFilters/{filterName}?api-version=2018-07-01";

                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Token);

                    var assetFilter = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new AssetFilter()
                    {
                        PresentationTimeRange = new PresentationTimeRange()
                        {
                            StartTimestamp = 100000000,
                            EndTimestamp = 150000000,
                            LiveBackoffDuration = 0,
                            Timescale = 10000000,
                            ForceEndTimestamp = false
                        },
                        Tracks = new List<FilterTrackSelection>()
                    });

                    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri);
                    request.Content = new StringContent(assetFilter, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

I'm sending the same AssetFilter object in both cases, any suggestions as to why the first call would fail?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The .Net SDK version 2.0.2 has updated the filters as per https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media/2.0.2.  I can't repro in 2.0.2 so it is likely fixed in this update.  The difference is likely that the REST call simply handles it properly.